# -webkit-mask gradient at the bottom of div

Tags: css, webkit

Its quite simple the effect I am after. I am simply trying to fade out the contents of a div into transparency.

However the `.card` div is variable height, and I only want a `30px` high gradient mask fixed to the bottom of the div.

The problem I am having, is getting the `no-repeat` area to be visible, rather than masked. I cant find much online about this. Can anyone help?

Or alternative solution.

See code here https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/vdj2b1mr/

*On the demo below, you can scroll the content inside each column. If you scroll down a little bit you will see the bottom the columns where the 30px mask is. But I need above the mask to visible. I only need the bottom 30px to fade out to transparent (including content)*

```css
@import "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata";

BODY {
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/gywUcTN.png");
}

.container {
  padding: 30px;
}

.card {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-width: 0;
  
  /* mask css */
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-position: 0 100%;
  -webkit-mask-size: 100% 30px;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(black), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  -webkit-mask-composite: initial;
  
}

.card-body {
  padding: 30px;
}

#example-1 {
  height: 200px;
}

#example-2 {
  height: 400px;
}

#example-3 {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4" id="example-1">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" id="example-2">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4" id="example-3">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: If i understood correctly, you want 30px from the bottom of the card to be fading to white no matter what height the card is.

Comment: Not white, to transparent.

Comment: Is [This](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkjyowz5/) close enough ?

Comment: Basically, i'll update my code to suit. Even tho the heights are variable in my demo, my real code will have overflow scroll. So i need all the contents to masked too, not just the background gradient.

Comment: I've updated my code/fiddles. So you can see the scrolling content inside the `.card`. Hopefully this makes sense now. Thanks

Comment: How about [now](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkjyowz5/2/)

Comment: Yep that is it. So weird I tried using calc, but i was using webkit-gradient and my sass wouldn't compile, and I wasn't using `to bottom` but yeah this works perfect thank you. You don't need the +30px on the transparent position, because that makes it a 60px gradient. The transparent location can be 100%. Thank you. Put it into an answer and I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: it was really just a trial and error, cuz i never worked with masks before, i'm glad it worked :)

Comment: Same but i never got calc to work in my gradient tho. Thanks again dude

Comment: My pleasure. :)